# Can someone help me understand anonymous functions in C#?

Tags: c#, anonymous-function

I'm currently following a Unity course. In one of the lessons, the lecturer uses an anonymous function that sorts the results by `actionValue.`

Here's the relevant code:

```cs
public EnemyAIAction GetBestEnemyAIAction()
{
    List<EnemyAIAction> enemyAIActionList = new List<EnemyAIAction>();
    List<GridPosition> validActionGridPositionList = GetValidActionGridPositionList();

    foreach(GridPosition gridPosition in validActionGridPositionList)
    {
        EnemyAIAction enemyAIAction = GetEnemyAIAction(gridPosition);
        enemyAIActionList.Add(enemyAIAction);
    }

    enemyAIActionList.Sort(
        (EnemyAIAction a, EnemyAIAction b) => b.actionValue - a.actionValue
    );
}
```

The lecturer doesn't bother explaining *why* this approach sorts the list by actionValue. I'm having trouble understanding how, exactly, subtracting the inputs from each other sorts the list by that input value.

Comment: Assuming `actionValue` is a number you can check on paper what happens when either side is larger than the other. Unless your confusion is about what values the `Sort` method expects to determine which element should be sorted before which other

Comment: Sort can accept a function to execute, which requires two parameters. Those are "declared" inline, the function body is given by `=>`. Collection is sorted based on the value returned by `Sort` (an integer). See, e.g., https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: See explanation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=net-7.0 for how `Sort` expects a sorting method to work. Less than zero / zero / greater than zero explains one item comes before the other, or they should be sorted as equal, or one comes after the other.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm really struggling with this. What do the parameters refer to? In the example I gave, what exactly are EnemyAction a and EnemyAction b? Is Sort() looping through the list and in filling in those values?

For example, the first loop would be enemyAIActionList[0] and enemyAIActionList[1] presumably?

Comment: Think of them as one-line functions. For example, if you wanted a function that squares the argument you can do this with `(x) => x*x`, instead of declaring a method and referring to the method where needed. It just makes things simpler as you focus on what the function _does_ and not how it is declared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Sort` method is declared as

```cs
public void Sort (Comparison<T> comparison);
```

`Comparison<T>` is declared as

```cs
public delegate int Comparison<in T>(T x, T y);
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1), it returns *A signed integer that indicates the relative values of x and y, as shown in the following table.*

| Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| Less than 0 | x is less than y. |
| 0 | x equals y. |
| Greater than 0 | x is greater than y. |

I.e., the `Sort` method expects a delegate. You can think of a delegate as the address of a function. In this specific case the function accepts two items of the list as input parameters. The return value is a negative `int` when `x` is less than `y`, `0` when both items are considered as equal, and a positive `int` when `x` is greater than `y`.

Now you could declare your own method like this to sort in ascending order:

```cs
int EnemyAIActionComparison(EnemyAIAction x, EnemyAIAction y)
{
    if (x.actionValue > y.actionValue) return +1;
    if (x.actionValue < y.actionValue) return -1;
    return 0; // both are equal
}
```

Since it does not matter how large the result is (only the sign matters), you could simply write

```cs
int EnemyAIActionComparison(EnemyAIAction x, EnemyAIAction y)
{
    return x.actionValue - y.actionValue;
}
```

Then call the Sort method like this:

```cs
enemyAIActionList.Sort(EnemyAIActionComparison);
```

Note that no braces must follow `EnemyAIActionComparison()` because we are not calling the method here, we are passing the method itself as a parameter to `Sort`. `Sort` then calls this method on many pairs of list items according to a sorting algorithm (e.g., Quick Sort) until the list is sorted.

Now, there is  a shortcut in defining this method: you can use a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions). A lambda expression is a very concise syntax for declaring an anonymous method on the fly.

So `(x, y) => x.actionValue - y.actionValue` is equivalent to the method above. The type of the parameters is inferred from the declaration `int Comparison<in T>(T x, T y)` and `T` is given in the declaration of the list. So, you do not need to specify it as in the example you have given. (Note that the names you give to the parameters does not matter. Specifically, they do not need to be the same as in the declaration of `Comparison`.)

If you want to sort in descending order, just swap the signs, i.e., swap the values in the subtraction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I feel like I'm getting there.

So in the example I gave: 

enemyAIActionList.Sort((EnemyAIAction a, EnemyAIAction b) => b.actionValue - a.actionValue);

Does the sort loop through the enemyAIActionList?

For example, are EnemyAIAction a and EnemyAIAction b the first two items on the list the first time it runs?

Comment: My apologies. I responded to you too quickly, before your edits. I think I'm almost getting it. The mental equivalent of it being on the tip of my tongue. The only part tripping me up was what the parameters represented.

I'm now assuming it loops through the list. So comparing [0] and [1] then [1] and [2] (perhaps [2] and [3] for the second loop).

Comment: It loops through the list comparing all elements against each other to find the right order. The used algorithm for sort here is a Quick Sort.

Comment: Yes, the `Sort` method calls this comparison method as often as required and in the order required on pairs of list items as required by the sort algorithm used.